# Restore group access after Telegram Group Owner / Admin delete own account?

Tags: telegram

Unfortunately I deleted my Telegram account, now I created my account again with same mobile number, but now I lost my old existing Telegram group admin access.

My group is public and there is no other admin inside my group through which I can get admin access again.

Now I want to delete my old Telegram group. Is it possible?

Comment: Hi, welcome! Can you elaborate a bit more about the group type? public/private? more people or just you? more admins with full rights? can the other admins add you as admin? Try to give as much information you can about the situation (in the question - edit it). You can tag me here in the comment after you update the question and I'll re-look

Comment: My group is public and there is no other admin inside my group through which I can get admin access again.

Comment: As far as I know you can't, but maybe someone else will have another insight

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not *currently* possible, you can only transfer admin rights or group ownership to someone *before* you delete the account. Right now the best you can do is create an identical group and share an invite link to that in your previous public group to invite people there.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

But all mobile account no available
But owner deleted account showing